# How to use MKMapKit to generate polyline for Continental United States Boundary?

Tags: mkmapview, mapkit, mkoverlay, mkpolyline

*Note: If this question requires more information, please add a comment.*

**Details:**

I would like to generate a boundary line around the continental United States on an MKMapView. The idea is to begin drawing overlays on the area outside of the country outline (I need to de-emphasize external areas and just have the US be the primary focal point; I am considering a blur effect but would be open to suggestions on implementation or other methods to achieve the objective).

**Background:**

I need to blur out (or de-emphasize) the other countries that appear in the default MKMapView other than the Continental US.

**My Initial Approach:**

1. Identify the contiguous country boundary box using polylines
   (similar to how a bus route is represented on the map; I note there
   seems to be some default line ~ any method to access those
   coordinates?)
2. Identify a method to mask the map using a UIVisualEffectView with
   blur  (or any other possibility to dim that portion of the map not
   inside the boundary)

I don't necessarily need a code solution (though if posted, I'll try it). I am wondering if someone experienced in this area could provide pseudo code or just some pointers as to the best approach to take on this process.

**Other Research:**

I have reviewed other sources, including the [MapKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008210) and this [overlay tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30001/overlay-images-and-overlay-views-with-mapkit-tutorial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to draw a polygon around all your MKMapView with an inner polygon that would be the area you don't want to blur out.
Here is my solution:

First you need the coordinates to cover every bit of the map:

```swift
struct WorldCoordinates {
    static let values = [
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 90, longitude: 0),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 90, longitude: 180),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -90, longitude: 180),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -90, longitude: 0),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -90, longitude: -180),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 90, longitude: -180)
    ]
}
```

Then use a method like this one to add your inner and outer polygons:
Please note that I use "City" as an example of a struct with boundigCoordinatesArray being an array of the bounding coordinates of the area you don't want to blur.

```swift
func addCityBoundingPolygon(in mapView: MKMapView, with city: City) {
    // Declare your inner polygon
    let innerPolygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: city.boundingCoordinatesArray, count: city.boundingCoordinatesArray.count)
    innerPolygon.title = "\(city.id)"
        
    // Declare your outer polygon with previously created inner polygon
    let outerPolygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: WorldCoordinates.values, count: WorldCoordinates.values.count, interiorPolygons: [innerPolygon])
        
    mapView.addOverlay(outerPolygon)    
}
```

Finally add the color of your outer polygon on your MKMapViewDelegate like this:

```swift
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    if let polygon = overlay as? MKPolygon {
        let renderer = MKPolygonRenderer(polygon: polygon)
        renderer.fillColor = UIColor.outOfCityBounds().withAlphaComponent(0.1)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.outOfCityBounds().withAlphaComponent(0.4)
        renderer.lineWidth = 1
        return renderer
    }

    return MKOverlayRenderer()
}
```

With this approach you will be able to recreate something like this:
[image: Urbvan App]